# Error: Cannot convert value type GameScene to expected argument SKScene

Tags: swift, error-handling, sprite-kit

```
func Restart(){

    self.view?.presentScene(GameScene, transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0))



}
```

}

Error: Cannot convert value type GameScene to expected argument SKScene

I've been getting the above error and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sending the `type` GameScene as a parameter? otherwise you should stop naming your variables with capital letter. It looks like you are sending a type instead of an instance. (should probably be **gameScene**)
2. Your `GameScene` class might not inherit `SKScene`. The function `presentScene` takes an `SKScene` as a parameter and what you send in there has to be of the type `SKScene` or a class that **inherits** `SKScene`.

Comment: The class I'm getting 

`class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    
    
`

does have SKScene and GameScene is a class not sure what else could be wrong

Comment: You can't send in the class type to the function. You have to instantiate it like `var gameScene = GameScene()`and then send `gameScene` in to the function